# Adobe Native Extension for Android onActivityResult

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I created a Native Extension to use the zxing app (via an intent) on Android.

The app launches fine and scans the barcode.

I just can't get the result back into my Flex project. It seems that the onActivityResult method never gets called by the native extension.

Can you guys perhaps help?

Below is the code:

```
public class BarcodeScanFunction implements FREFunction {

public static BarcodeExtensionContext _context;


@Override
public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] passedArgs) {

    _context = (BarcodeExtensionContext)context;

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    context.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


    return null;
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult ir = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);


    _context.dispatchStatusEventAsync("DATA_CHANGED", ir.getContents());

}
 }
```

The Actionscript handler:

```
public class NativeBarcode extends EventDispatcher
{
    private static var extContext:ExtensionContext = null;

    public function NativeBarcode(target:IEventDispatcher=null)
    {
        super(target);

        if ( !extContext )
        {
            extContext = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("za.co.flatrocksolutions.Barcode","barcode");
            extContext.call("initMe");
        }
    }

    public static function get isSupported():Boolean
    {
        var toReturn:Boolean = false;

        toReturn = extContext.call("isSupported") as Boolean;

        return toReturn;
    }

    public function scan():void
    {
        extContext.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onStatus); 

        extContext.call("scanMe");
    } 

    public function onStatus(event:StatusEvent):void { 
        //dispatchEvent(event);

        var e : StatusEvent = new StatusEvent("DATA_CHANGED", true, false, event.code, event.level);
        dispatchEvent(e);

    }
}
```

Using the ANE:

```
be = new NativeBarcode();
            be.addEventListener("DATA_CHANGED", onStatus);
            be.scan();
```

....

```
private function onStatus(e:StatusEvent):void 
            {      
                if (e.code == "DATA_CHANGED") 
                {
                    var stringData:String = e.level;
                    // ...
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't as slick, but I have done this by launching the barcode app from the custom url, not native extension. After the barcode is scanned properly the barcode app copies it to the clipboard (it does this by default). The user presses back twice to return to the app where we can then read the text from the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider just capturing the barcode image and decoding it right inside your own app with actionscript.  I've done this myself with a QR code reader in an app myself quite easily so I can confirm that the zxing library works just fine in flex/actionscript.

Here's a video I did of the proof of concept for it about a year ago : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHWTwxnPfHw

You simply fire a camera capture and then use the zxing library to decode it.  It is already ported and available in actionscript.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/  (look for the actionscript source in the library download)

If you need more information than that I'll try to dig up some source for you...  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the FREFunction instance to listen to the onActivityResult. What you need to do is start a new Activity and implement that function there:

So firstly you'll need to create a new activity:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity 
{
    public static int UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE   =  444444;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
        startActivityForResult( intent, UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == UNIQUE_REQUEST_CODE)
         {
             // do stuff
         }
         this.finish();
    }
}
```

Then in your FREFunction.call implementation you need to start this activity.

```
Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context.getActivity(), SomeActivity.class);
context.getActivity().startActivity( startActivityIntent );
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Michael said, you need to create your own activity and override the onCreate and onActivityResult methods. For some reason, this still didn't work for me. After a few hours of banging my head, I realized that the activity needs to be in your Android application manifest. You can do this by opening your AIR application descriptor xml file and inserting the following into your manifestAdditions tag.

```
<application>
    <activity android:name="insert.ane.path.here.ZXingActivityYouCreated"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can implement onActivityResult for FREObject, check here [[Android] Getting onActivityResult and onStart/onPause/.... events from AIR activity [solution]](http://forums.adobe.com/message/6194756?tstart=0) . It shows how to implement it on FREContext but I have used it to implement on FREObject